# Replace "follow" in "Something follows the following steps"

Tags: synonyms

The sentence "The analysis follows the following steps" doesn't sound good, but I can't think of a more formal synonym to either of the follow-s.

Comment: The analysis proceeds as follows:

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about writing advice.

Answer (score 8):

> "The analysis follows the following steps"

1. the steps below
2. consists of the following steps
3. was made by following the steps below
4. The following steps were taken in order to create this analysis.
5. **The following steps were taken in order to analyze this [problem].**

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear to me what you mean by the first *follows*. If you mean the analysis *was performed according to* the following steps, then say that:

> The analysis was performed according to the following steps.
> The analysis was performed according to these steps.
> The analysis was performed according to the following:
> The analysis was performed as follows.

If you mean you're going to present some steps and then present the analysis, you could say

> The analysis will be presented after the following steps.
> The analysis will be presented after these steps.
> The analysis will be presented after the following:

If you mean the analysis is the logical consequence of the following steps:

> The analysis derives from the following steps.
> The analysis follows from these steps.
> The analysis is based on the following steps.

Answer (score 2):

The analysis is based on the following steps. 
The analysis follows the coming steps or the next steps.

Answer (score 2):

**The analysis is confirmed by the following steps.**

**The following steps outline the analysis**

But I think @Josh61 made a better suggestion with:

**The analysis follows the next steps.**